# SPD Workflows upgrade from 2007 to 2010 fix

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-designer, upgrade

Our company has several large SharePoint farms that are migrating over time.  As a result of the upgrade, our URL's will change.  Our technology group has said that any workflows created in Designer will NOT work because of the URL change.

In the past I have been able to copy a workflow from one site to another in SPD2007 and then do a "Find and Replace" for the LIST ID to use the same workflows on multiple sites.

QUESTION:  Would it be possible to do a "Find and Replace" in SPD2010 to all my workflows once our site is upgraded?  If so, would I need to replace just the URL's or will the list id's or any other id numbers change?

Please note: I only have access to SharePoint Designer, not admin access or VB and our technology group does not offer any support in upgrading customized sited.

Answer (score 4):

The upgrade should allow the current SPD workflows to function normally, however, any URLs that are not relative links will be  the items that will not function properly with an upgrade that changes the URL. IDs on lists should stay the same.